# In python i am trying to get the emoji in my text(by using get function), but i am getting this error as none when i run the code

Tags: python-3.x

```
   emoji = {
    ':)': '',
    ':(': ''
}
message = input('> ')
split = message.split(" ")

for x in split:
    if ":)" in split:
        print(f' {message} {emoji.get(x)}')
        break
    elif ":(" in split:
     print(f' {message} {emoji.get(x)}')
    break
```

** when I type in input, for Eg:
hi Hello :)

I get the output as
"hi Hello :) None"

instead of none, I want emoji in place of :)

Comment: You're checking `if ":)" in split`, but you fetch the emoji with `emoji.get(x)`, and `x` is `hi` at this point…!

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get` method returns `None` when a match is not found, here is the refactored code:

```py
EMOTICON_TO_EMOJI = {":)": "", ":(": ""}


def replace_emoji(text: str):
    for emoticon, emoji in EMOTICON_TO_EMOJI.items():
        text = text.replace(emoticon, emoji)
    return text


message = input("> ")
print(replace_emoji(message))
```

Example use:

```
> Hello there AbhiExplores and future stackoverflow seekers :)
Hello there AbhiExplores and future stackoverflow seekers
```